# Unique job with NSOperationQueue

Tags: iphone, ios

On an iPhone project I have an NSOperationQueue, which handles communication to a server, on my appDelegate object and an upload job as following:

```
@interface UploadOperation : NSOperation

- (id)initWithItem:(NSDictionary*)anItem;

@end
```

I'm pushing items, with the user's request, to the NSOperationQueue which fire the upload. Everything works great, but I want to prevent the same upload operation to occur more then 1 time.
In other words, if the upload was not finish, don't push the same item to the upload queue.

Is it possible with NSOperationQueue methods or I'll have to manage it by my own with an "items currently on queue" array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, you need to manage it by using your own array of items that are currently on the queue:

```
NSArray *allQueueItems = ....;
NSMutableArray *queueItems = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSOperation *item in allQueueItems) {
    [self.operationQueue addOperation:item];
    [queueItems addObject:item];
}
```

Comment: eventually, out of the given answers, I've decided to go with a simple solution as this one maybe because this queue will have maximum of 3 objects and to subclass/overwrite messages seems like a waste of time...

Answer (score 9):

First ensure your `NSOperation` subclass' [`hash`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/hash) and [`isEqual:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isEqual:) are implemented such that two instances trying to upload the same content are considered equal.

Then before adding a new operation, check first to see if there is already an identical operation in the queue by calling [`containsObject:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BABCEJDI) on the array returned by calling [`operations`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004592-RH2-SW8) on `NSOperationQueue`.

Answer (score 3):

You could subclass `NSOperationQueue` and override the `addOperation:` method to check and make sure this new operation is one you haven't seen recently (or one that is currently enqueued).

You could maintain your own list of recent operations, or use the operation queue's `-operations` method to return the currently enqueued operations.

Then just use your custom operation queue subclass instead.

Comment: There's no need to fear, Dave is here. ;)

Answer (score 2):

It's actually been done for you: https://github.com/mronge/CTUniqueOperationQueue